# Prompt-based image generative AI tool for editing specific details

Tags: image-generation, fine-tuning, dall-e

I am trying to make some spritesheets using DALLE3, and while the initial generation of spritesheets by DALLE3 are fascinating, I have encountered these problems:

1. Inconsistent art style(multiple spritesheets must all have the same artstyle)
2. Inconsistent motion(while prompt engineering can sometimes solve this, it is a frequent issue)
3. Inability of DALLE to return results that match specific requirements, such as different eye shape while keeping the rest of the sprite intact

Are there any **huggingface** tools or a mini-LLM gen AI that can edit spritesheets or sprites generated by DALLE based on more tailored requirements? Or is the **OpenAI API** a lot better in editing images or spritesheets in a specific manner? Essentially, I'm looking for something that can edit sprites or spritesheets already made by DALLE in a more specific way based on prompts and received sprite input.

If there aren't any, since I have experience in machine learning, I am willing to make one, given that it is not too difficult. If someone has done this already, what are some suggestions?

Comment: **To community:** Instead of dropping downvote spam, please *explain* how a question should be improved. This question is perfectly reasonable if you ask me. Countering with an upvote...